# Does VBA handle XQuery?

Tags: xml, vba, xquery

Can VBA parse XQueries against an XML source?

Using Microsoft XML, v6.0 in combination with WinHTTP, I am able to pull data into VBA just fine. Furthermore, I am also able to run XPath queries against it, but it lacks the power of XQuery.

My source XML data is moderately complex, and I need to join data across multiple ancestries in the source to form my desired output. I have already designed a working XQuery, but when I turn to VBA, I can't find any way of applying it to my XML source.

Comment: [This post](https://roymacleanvba.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/analysing-cross-references-between-documents/) seems to suggest that it does.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I did try to read the article by Roy MacLean, but I couldn't make enough sense of it to derive any applicable wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSXML 6.0 only has XPath 1.0 support. You need to interface an external XQuery processor.

The post Robert Harvey referenced to uses [Qizx](http://www.xmlmind.com/qizx/) (which is discontinued). [BaseX seems to have VB support](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients), but I'm not sure whether this is for VB 6 or VB.net. Checking other relevant XQuery implementations (eXist DB, Saxon) didn't bring me any VB 6 interfaces, but all of them - including BaseX - have other APIs like REST interfaces.

[rts-xquery](http://www.rtslink.com/rts-xquery-library/using-rts-xquery-dll-in-vb6.html) also claims to offer XQuery support, but I don't know anything about it. [Altova was proposed in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718405/using-saxon-from-vb6) and might be worth looking at.